# Consult the mot problem of the openGauss database

Tags: open-gauss

After the MOT transaction in the openGauss database is complete, the local memory is not released. How can I find the cause?

Answer (score 0):

OpenGauss provides two functions to check the memory usage of MOT transactions. You are advised to use the function to query:

- mot_session_memory_detail(): checks the MOT memory usage of all sessions.
- mot_local_memory_detail(): checks the size of the MOT local memory, including data and indexes.

thanks